# How to copy the primary key from another table as my form's field default value in APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I got a "user" table and a "student" table, in user table there are some attributes such as user_id, lname, fname and gender, in student table there are some other attribute such as course, WAM and user_id as foreign key to join student table with user table.

Now I am creating a form for user to register account.
I created a form for user to insert data into user table, after clicking the "next" button it will come to another form to let user insert data into student table.

How can I bring the user_id from the previous form into the second form as default value so data in both table can join together?

For example in first form the user got his user_id as 10002, and I want to bring this value into second form's user_id field as default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two pages, right?

**Page 1, user data:**

- create a button ("Next", as you said)
- in its "Behavior" section, set action to **Redirect to page in this application**
- click the "Target" button and

  - set it to go to page 2
  - set items: name = `P2_ID`, value = `&P1_ID.` (pay attention to leading ampersand and trailing dot)

**Page 2, student data:**

- it should contain the P2_ID item which will accept value transferred from page 1
- use that value while storing student's data into the table

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I follow the step what you suggested, however, when I click on the "next" button and proceed to page 2, user_id still remain empty, and when I check my data base, data inserted in page 1 is not recorded in my database, how can I solve this? Additional information: I put the button in the "CREATE" box in region area.

Comment: You're welcome. If you did it correctly, then `:P2_ID` would have a value. If nothing was saved into the table, then you didn't submit page 1. In order to do that, let the P1_BTN_NEXT button **submit**; then create a **branch** which would redirect you to page 2 (set all those settings I mentioned previously to the branch).

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, can I know where can I create the branch? Do you mean set the button to submit the page and after submit let the page remain in page 1, then create another button as "next"? Or you mean when creating the form, set the "Branch Here on Submit" as page 2? but if I did like this I'm not able to do the set item step in my behaviour. Additional information, in page 1, user are not able to set the user_id manually as I set the user_id increase by one when a new record created

Comment: Branch is on the Processes tab. There'll be only one button on Page 1: P1_NEXT. It'll submit the page. On submit, you'd branch to Page 2 (don't remain on Page 1, that's useless). Regardless of how USER_ID is set, submit will save it into the table and it'll be in session state so you'll be able to transfer it to page 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I solved everything!! Just a little issue now, if the user create a new account, he finished fill in page 1 form and currently in page 2, but he click cancel, how can I remove the record saved in page 1 when the user click cancel in page 2? Or else there will have a half done record in my table

Comment: Just the same as with the P1_NEXT button. Create a process which will remove user data, and create a branch which will redirect you *somewhere else*.